# UIView animation unwinding at random

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, mkmapview

I have an area of screen that is approximately 2/3 of the total screen area, in this area are two objects a MKMapView and a UITableView. On button press I would like to swap the sizes between the two with a little resize animation. The CGRects are calculated like so:

```
//Calculate initial screen item sizes
int mapTypeButtH=20;

int baseX=5;
int baseY=self.but_mapHybrid.frame.origin.y+self.but_mapHybrid.frame.size.height;
int baseW=310;
int availableSpace=self.view.frame.size.height-baseY;

posMapMinor=CGRectMake(baseX,baseY,baseW,(availableSpace/10)*2);
posListMajor=CGRectMake(baseX,baseY+((availableSpace/10)*2),baseW,(availableSpace/10)*8);

posMapMajor=CGRectMake(baseX,baseY,baseW,(availableSpace/10)*8);
posListMinor=CGRectMake(baseX,baseY+((availableSpace/10)*8),baseW,(availableSpace/10)*2);
```

That all comes out fine, and I have checked the values it produces, then on button press I have tried all manner of configurations to execute the animation itself, none have worked properly. The current attempt is like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.mapView.frame=posMapMinor;
}completion: ^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.tbl_actions.frame=posListMajor;
    }completion: ^(BOOL finished){

    }];
}];
```

It seems no matter what I try when I execute the animation, it will malfunction in some way, whether that be only one animation playing, or both playing and then snapping back to position. Is there some basic lesson in the docs that I have missed? It seems such a basic task to carry out. Any tips or ideas on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: I have narrowed the issue a little further, it would appear that if only one animation is fired the animation plays properly and the view stays in position. However, if both are called simultaneously or chained (even with a delay) both unwind and the views go back to where they were. The result is weird sort flicker and then nothing.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have know idea what was causing this problem, however the solution I found was to wrap the UITableView in a UIView and carry out the animations on the UIView. Once I did that it worked perfectly.